# Is the 3rd party vendor Amazing Armory still around?

Tags: shopping

I heard that he was a scammer, but he made some good stuff and quite a few people have some of the great visors and guns he made.

Answer (score 3):

I realize that it's a late answer, but ToyWiz and BrickArsenal.com just started carrying this line, and Amazing Armory is active on Flickr. Also, Firestar in the UK carries it. I hope that helps.

Also, I work for ToyWiz.com and Brickarsenal :)

Comment: Cheers Bebs, and thanks for the full disclosure ;)

Answer (score 2):

the most complete info i found was on [brickblogger.com](http://thebrickblogger.com/2011/03/amazing-armory-overview/). the [amazing-armory homepage](http://amazingarmory.com/) still isn't online ("coming soon") - just like it was about a half year ago when the article was written. at that time you could buy parts on [bricklink.com](http://www.bricklink.com/store.asp?p=UNITED_ARMORY) and [firsestartoys.com](http://www.firestartoys.com/) where i can't find them today.

the unavailability on bricklink in addition with the still-not-online webpage pretty much sounds like amazing armory is out of business - but i don't have facts that prove this speculation.